# Laravel 5 Repeat ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with double id in the relationship

relation / model:

```
public function pp(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pp',"pfield","id")
            ->join('other',"other.id",'=','Pp.product');
    }
```

controller:

```
   $pp = $psmf->pp;
        print_r($pp);
```

I needs to have twice id but I can not do, tables look like:

```
  |id|name|sth1|sth2
  |1 |asfa|afsf|faxc
  .................

  next table:
  |id|sth3|sth4
  |1 |asdg|afsg
  |2 |awer|qerq
  |3 |retr|gdfg
```

I would like to print_r show the data in such a way.

```
  [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => asfa
                            [sth1] => afsf
                            [sth2] => faxc
                            [id] => 1
                            [sth3] => asdg
                            [sth4] => afsg
                        ),
                        Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => asfa
                            [sth1] => afsf
                            [sth2] => faxc
                            [id] => 2
                            [sth3] => awer
                            [sth4] => qerq
                        ),
                        Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => asfa
                            [sth1] => afsf
                            [sth2] => faxc
                            [id] => 3
                            [sth3] => retr
                            [sth4] => gdfg
                        )
```

Basically you need to use your script twice tables ID. Unfortunately, in this my way to all the data well but ID is overwritten.
In a simple sql code, what it needs to do it would look like this:

```
select id as "first_id",name,sth1,sth2,id as "Sec_id",sth3,sth4
```

And in this way I could use the id 2 times

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use like this in controller

```
    $variableName = modelName::with('modelFunction')->first();
```

or

```
    $variableName = modelName::with('modelFunction')->get();
```

You can remove the join from model and use it after with() before ->first/get().